# ¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?

Tags: soporte, faq, comentarios, notificaciones

> Esta publicación está basada en la pregunta [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/209901)

- ¿A quién puedo enviar @respuestas?
- ¿Cómo respondo a un usuario en concreto al escribir un comentario?
- ¿Serán notificados esos usuarios?
- ¿A qué se refiere la gente cuando menciona "hacer un ping" a otro usuario?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Esta es una traducción libre de [la respuesta en inglés](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/209901). No dudes en agregar todo aquello que vaya añadiéndose en la respuesta original, así como corregir aquello que cambie o no esté bien traducido.

Puedes utilizar la sintaxis *@nombre* en cualquier punto de un comentario para contestar a un usuario concreto. Esto notificará a ese usuario en su [Bandeja de entrada global](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/). También podrás recibir [notificaciones en tu correo electrónico](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/) si así lo configuras en las preferencias de tu perfil.

#### ¿Quién es notificado con esta funcionalidad?

- El autor de la publicación.

  El autor de la publicación *siempre* será notificado de cualquier comentario. Sin embargo, puede ser bueno usarlo por claridad, si es necesario; no obstante, si hasta el momento solamente tú y el autor han comentado en la publicación, la parte *@nombre* será [eliminada automáticamente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099) del principio del comentario, pues no añade valor.
- Cualquier persona que tenga un comentario visible (no borrado) en la publicación.

  Si un usuario comenta en su propia publicación y solamente otra persona ha comentado en él previamente, esa persona [también es notificada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts) si *@nombre* no se incluye.
- Cualquier usuario que haya editado la publicación (esto no incluye sugerencias pendientes o rechazadas).
- Para preguntas: el moderador o el propietario de la medalla de oro que cerró o reabrió la pregunta. Los usuarios que hayan cerrado o reabierto la pregunta *sin* que no tengan voto de cierre *binding* (coercitivo, es decir, aquellos que no tengan medalla de oro en una de las etiquetas o un voto de moderador), no pueden ser notificados.
- Para preguntas: cualquier usuario que ofrezca una recompensa en la pregunta (actual o expirado).

Ten en cuenta que la pregunta y las respuestas son consideradas independientemente. Por ejemplo, si Alicia es la autora de la pregunta, no puedes notificarla mediante un comentario en la respuesta de Benito (a menos que Alicia *también* haya participado en esa respuesta). De la misma forma, no puedes notificar a Benito comentando en la pregunta de Alicia.

#### ¿Por qué algunos nombres no aparecen en la caja de autocompletado?

La caja de autocompletado puede determinar cuándo un *@nombre* no será necesario para lanzar una notificación. En ese caso no incluirá al usuario en la lista.

Además, solamente los usuarios que han comentado en la publicación aparecen en esa lista. Los editores y otros usuarios del historial de la publicación no aparecerán nunca allí, incluso si pueden ser notificados escribiéndolos manualmente.

#### ¿Puedo notificar a más de una persona en una vez?

No. Los comentarios que contienen más de un *@nombre* [son bloqueados](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-user-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings/2615#2615) a menos que contengan una tilde abierta `` ` ``.
En el último caso, solamente el primer nombre mencionado usando la sintaxis *@nombre* será [notificado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment/35914#35914). Por ejemplo, *@Alicia `@benito ¡Hola!`* notificará a Alicia (si ha participado en esa publicación), pero no a Benito.

Una excepción a esto es el caso cuando el primer *@nombre* no encaja con nadie, o encaja con el autor de la publicación (por lo que no es necesario); en ese caso, el siguiente *@nombre* será revisado.

#### ¿Puedo modificar quién es notificado después de publicar un comentario?

```
# Nota del traductor: esto no está nada claro
```

Al editar un comentario dentro de su período limitado de edición, si cambias o añades *@nombre*, [la notificación puede o no llegar al nuevo destinatario](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees/74781#74781) según el *timing*.

#### ¿Hay palabras clave especiales para notificar a los usuarios?

No. Cosas como [*@op*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52368/does-op-also-notify-the-op), [*@downvoter*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post), *@all* o *@todos* no tienen ningún significado especial y no lanzarán notificación alguna.

#### ¿Cómo se comprueban los nombres?

- Debes incluir *@nombre*, donde *nombre* es una coincidencia razonable con el [actual nombre](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/481203#481203) en el momento en el que el comentario se envía. No puedes usar un nombre anterior que el destinatario tuviera.
- La notificación debe empezar con un espacio o estar al principio del comentario. Por ejemplo, [no puedes usar estilos](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-quote-about-programming/1079#comment-19850) como cursivas.
- Si la primera palabra en el nombre del usuario tiene al menos tres caracteres, entonces debe haber una coincidencia que no distingue mayúsculas de minúsculas y que debe empezar por los mismos caracteres. Esto quiere decir que *@a* y *@ab* nunca coincidirán con nadie, [a menos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61960/allow-for-comment-reply-to-usernames-with-less-than-three-characters-in-first-wor/75809#75809) que un usuario utilice una primera palabra de solamente dos caracteres. Por ejemplo: *@Ju* notificará a Juan Valdez, pero no a Juan, y *@B.* notificará a B. Villamarín, pero no B.Fidus. Si hay más de tres caracteres en *@nombre*, entonces todos los caracteres dados deben coincidir (ni *@alix* ni *@aliciaenelpais* servirán para notificar al usuario Alicia).
- La búsqueda de coincidencias se realiza en orden cronológico inverso, por lo que si cinco personas llamadas Juan están participando, *@juan* coincidirá con el último Juan. (Usa la siguiente regla para diferenciarlos)
- Los espacios se eliminan *del nombre* para realizar la búsqueda de coincidencias. Así, para notificar a Juan Valdez puedes usar *@jua*, *@juan* o *@juanvaldez*. Las dos últimas opciones son útiles si también Juan Ito está participando, que entonces puede ser distinguido usando *@juani*. Sin embargo, no se permiten espacios en el mismo *@nombre*. Así que para notificar a J Valdez, debes usar *@jva* o *@jvaldez*. (Aquí, *@J Valdez* sería interpretado solamente como *@J*, que es demasiado corto). Comillas simples, puntos, guiones y guiones bajos [no deberían](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies/51913#51913) ser eliminados.
- Los caracteres especiales [son eliminados](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48968/peter-works-for-peter/49409#49409) con su equivalente simple. Para contestar a Piëre puedes usar tanto *@piëre* como *@piere*. Y para responder a Jörg puedes usar *@jorg*, [pero no](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89051/joerg-works-for-jorg) *@joerg*.
- La notificación solo funciona para el nombre [actual](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/481203#481203) en el momento en el que el comentario se envía, no para cualquier nombre anterior que el usuario haya tenido.

#### ¿Hay alguna otra puntuación que afecte a la notificación?

El sistema intenta ignorar la mayor parte de la puntuación para permitir notificaciones apropiadas, como los puntos finales, la coma o el punto y coma. Las reglas exactas de búsqueda de coincidencias no están documentadas, pero una serie de tests extensivos realizados el 30 de agosto de 2011 indican que el algoritmo usado es el siguiente:

- Coge la primera palabra inmediatamente después de la `@`, donde el límite de la palabra viene dado por un espacio, caracter no válido para nombres de usuario (como `: , / ! ?`) o el final del comentario.
- Elimina el punto final `.` de la cadena resultante si es necesario (si la cadena tiene más de dos caracteres).
- Si la cadena resultante termina en `'` o `'s`, elimina esa parte de la cadena.
- La cadena resultante se comparará con el nombre de usuario, cuyos espacios son eliminados.

Por ejemplo: El comentario termina por `@O'Conner's.)`. La palabra inmediatamente después de la `@` es `O'Conner's.` pues `'` y `.` son válidos en los nombres de usuario. Entonces, el punto final se elimina, y finalmente `'s` se elimina, resultando en `O'Conner`.

Algunos ejemplos de notificaciones admitidas:

- `@name some text`
- `@name: some text`
- `@name. Some text`
- `@name, some text`
- `some text, @name`
- `some text, @name, more text`
- `Some text, @name.`
- `Esto se menciona en @name's comentario.`
- `@P.` para tanto P. Smith como P. Jones (quien comentara hace menos tiempo), pero no P.Smith, ni P.Jones. De la misma forma, `@P. Smith` se gestiona como `@P.`, por lo que también vale para P. Smith o P. Jones.
- `@psm` o `@psmith` para P Smith
- `@peters` o `@peterj` para Peter Smith o Peter Jones, respectivamente
- `@name...`

Ejemplos que **no** generarán una notificación:

- `abc@name`
- `*@name*`
- `*@name:*`
- `[@name](http://some-url)`
- `@[name](http://some-url)`
- `@P Smith`