# ¿Cómo invitar a un chat privado a alguien?

Tags: soporte, faq, chat

¿Cómo invito a alguien a un chat privado?

Reviso sus perfiles pero no encuentro la opción, solo se muestra con algunos usuarios.

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Esta es una traducción de [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)
>   No dudes en añadir todo aquello que vaya añadiéndose en la respuesta original, así como corregir aquello que cambie o no esté bien traducido.

Los mensajes instantáneos o privados no están disponibles: ha habido solicitudes para implementarlos pero [han sido rechazadas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) para mantener el foco en las preguntas y las respuestas, y que estas sean visibles a todo el mundo.

Algunos usuarios utilizan [el chat](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/super-user-chat-now-available/), y puedes crear una sala de chat "privada" para ti y el usuario con el que te gustaría contactar. Esto puedes hacerlo visitando su perfil de usuario en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) (nótese que si no eres moderador, **no puedes** crear una sala privada - solamente puedes configurarla para que otros usuarios no puedan escribir en ella, **pero el resto de usuarios podrán leer los mensajes**):

[image: Usuario aleatorio]

Después cambia los parámetros de la sala a *Gallery mode* (o privado si eres moderador). Si el usuario nunca ha entrado en [Stack Exchange Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) pero tiene un perfil de Stack Overflow, puedes probar con el [Chat de Stack Overflow](http://chat.stackoverflow.com).

Puedes usar las [@respuestas en los comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1357/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-las-respuestas-en-los-comentarios) para notificar a un usuario. Pero recuerda: incluso los comentarios deben tener sentido en la publicación, por lo que pueden ser [reportados como ruidosos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) si no lo son, por lo que no está recomendado.

En los casos poco frecuentes en que una acción debe ser tomada inmediatamente (por ejemplo, si el usuario deja por error credenciales personales en una publicación), puedes [reportarlo para que los moderadores lo revisen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-question-for-moderator-review/24568#24568) y explicar de qué trata el tema urgente.

Por otra parte, si quieres poner a disposición una manera para que la gente te contacte, deja información de contacto en tu perfil de usuario.