# ¿Cuál es la forma de saber si una pregunta está en revisión y cuál es el estado de dicha revisión?

Tags: soporte, línea-de-tiempo

Me cerraron [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/64920/29967) al considerarla duplicada. Luego del cierre modifiqué la pregunta poniendo además una nota aclaratorio de por qué consideraba que ambas preguntas podrían ser consideradas relacionadas, pero no duplicadas.

Ante el silencio de quien cerró la pregunta la voté para reapertura y solicité la intervención de un moderador.

¿Hay alguna forma de saber si la pregunta está en revisión y cuál es el estado de dicha revisión? ¿O la pregunta quedará definitivamente cerrada? Si no hay posibilidad de reabrirla, ¿hay alguna forma de saberlo?

Comment: Al leer tu pregunta puedo notar que propones [**firmar un APK con un "certificado de depuración" a la Play Store**, el cual tiene una fecha de vencimiento de 365 días](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#expdebug), por lo cual, cuando caduque te arrojará un error de compilación. Para un usuario inexperto (como yo) en `Android`, estás proponiendo una mala práctica.

Comment: Una disculpa amigo A. Cedano, consideré que la información podría estar en la otra respuesta, pero algo que me pareció muy importante también es lo que comenta Davlio, precisamente por eso te preguntaba si usabas debug.keystore para firmar la aplicación para tienda. De hecho precisamente agregué esa información aquí : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8508/recuperar-llave-publicaci%C3%B3n-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android

Comment: Muchas gracias @Davlio era algo que yo tampoco sabía y que he descubierto gracias a la situación que se ha presentado. Cuando tenga tiempo modifico la pregunta/respuesta en caso de que la respuesta a la pregunta de Jorgesys no abarque toda esa información.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ante el silencio de quien cerró la pregunta la voté para reapertura

Nótese que quien cerró la pregunta no recibe notificación si la editas.

No es necesario ser verboso: si consideró que la pregunta debe cerrarse y utilizó su herramienta de medalla de oro, pues no necesita mayor explicación en su momento. Eso sí, puedes dirigirte a ella utilizando `@respuestas`, tal y como se detalla en [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83), y tener un debate al respecto.

> solicité la intervención de un moderador.

La apertura y clausura de preguntas es algo que la comunidad hace de forma autónoma y los reportes de moderación no tienen sentido de ser para estas cuestiones. Ignoro el volumen de reportes que reciben diariamente, pero la idea es que los moderadores actúen allá donde la comunidad no puede llegar por sí sola: juntar preguntas, bloquear usuarios irrespetuosos, convertir respuestas en comentarios...

> ¿Hay alguna forma de saber si la pregunta está en revisión y cuál es el estado de dicha revisión? ¿O la pregunta quedará definitivamente cerrada? Si no hay posibilidad de reabrirla, ¿hay alguna forma de saberlo?

Ninguna publicación tiene nunca un estado definitivo. Lo que ahora está abierto puede cerrarse y viceversa. Lo que ahora es visible puede borrarse y viceversa. Por tanto, su estado de "cerrado" actual bien puede cambiar si la comunidad así lo considera. Por tanto, no, la pregunta no quedará definitivamente cerrada.

Para ver las revisiones que se han hecho a la pregunta, puedes consultar su línea de tiempo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/64920/timeline Fíjate que la dirección consiste en `https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/` + identificador de la publicación + `/timeline` y toda publicación tiene una.

En este caso particular, vemos que ha habido dos intentos de reabrirla:

- https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/40759, con 3 votos a favor de mantenerla cerrada
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/40908, con 3 votos también en ese sentido

Nótese que en la línea de tiempo normal (la de moderador es algo diferente) solo salen las revisiones *completadas*. Por tanto, la que existe actualmente no figura.

Comment: @fedorqui: Edité el título y etiqueta de la pregunta porque me parece que la parte medular de la pregunta es `¿Hay alguna forma de saber si la pregunta está en revisión...`, lo otro, es parte del contexto pero no creo que, al menos en este hilo, deba de dársele prioridad a discutir lo que motivó al OP a hacer la pregunta. En cuanto a esta respuesta, mi sugerencia en concreto es poner en primer lugar lo del timeline.

Answer (score 0):

En Perfil > Actividad > n reportes útiles es posible ver tanto la lista de reportes como el resumen de los mismos.

Ligas quasi-directa (agregar número de usuario al final)

Sitio principal: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/

Meta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/