# Actualizar enlace en Comentar en Todas Partes

Tags: soporte, centro-de-ayuda

El artículo de ayuda sobre el privilegio [Comentar En Todas Partes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) incluye el enlace **¿Cómo funcionan las respuestas a comentarios?** pero apunta al hilo sobre el tema en Meta SE, sin embargo, ya contamos con nuestra propia versión en español:

[¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/65)

Solicito sea actualizado el enlace en cuestión.