# ¿El OP es notificado de cada comentario en cualquier respuesta a su pregunta?

Tags: soporte, comentarios, notificaciones, respuestas-a-comentarios

Cuando alguien plantea una pregunta es notificado de cada respuesta que es dada a dicha pregunta. Pero ¿qué ocurre con los **comentarios en las respuestas**? ¿También es notificado?

Supongamos el siguiente escenario:

- El OP plantea la pregunta
- Yo y otros más responden

En cada respuesta el OP es notificado.

A veces el OP comenta **en mi respuesta**. Y luego yo quiero responder a su comentario. **¿Si no lo menciono (al OP)  el mismo es notificado de mi comentario de todos modos?**

Me gustaría conocer ese dato ya que a veces necesitaría mencionar a otra persona distinta del OP en el comentario, si él es notificado de todas formas, entonces podría mencionar preferentemente a esa tercera persona.

Answer (score 2):

No, el OP no recibe notificación de los comentarios que se publican en las respuestas a su pregunta

Tal y como se comenta en [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83), las notificaciones se envían *siempre* al autor de una publicación.

Por tanto, si A pregunta y B responde:

- A recibirá notificación sobre todos los comentarios en su pregunta
- B recibirá notificación sobre todos los comentarios en su respuesta

Si luego resulta que A comenta en la respuesta de B, entonces podrá recibir notificación si la gente lo menciona con `@A`.

> A veces el OP comenta **en mi respuesta**. Y luego yo quiero responder a su comentario. **¿Si no lo menciono (al OP)  el mismo es notificado de mi comentario de todos modos?**

En este caso, hay dos opciones:

- Si nadie más comentó, cuando respondas al comentario no hace falta que menciones al OP, pues es la única persona "externa" en comentar.
- Si alguien más comentó, el OP solo será notificado si lo mencionas.

En ningún caso se pueden notificar a dos personas en un mismo comentario. La notificación solamente es para el autor de la publicación y una persona más.

Yo recomendaría que como regla general, siempre que dudes sobre un caso, uses `@usuario` para asegurarte de que llega.

Comment: Además, se puede ver si es necesario el `@usuario` observando el autocompletado, que sólo aparece cuando es necesario usarlo para que le llegue la notificación. Por ejemplo, ahora en esta respuesta, no va a haber autocompletado para `@f`, pero sí para `@M`.

Comment: Efectivamente, @Mar. Si bien el `@` tiene algunas cosas que no funcionan como querríamos: a los editores de una publicación no los recomienda; además, sugiere después de un punto, si bien en ese caso no llega la notificación ([If an @ is not going to notify a user, there should not be auto-complete for a user handle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307042/209901)).

Comment: No sabía de esas excepciones (aunque ahora veo que lo habías incluido en el FAQ). Agregado junto al resto de los post-its mentales de cómo funciona SO. Gracias!