# ¿si edito la pregunta lo verán los demás, o es mejor preguntar de nuevo?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, ediciones

Tengo esa duda: si preguntar de nuevo o editar la pregunta para que respondan de nuevo los usuarios. ¿Qué es mejor? Mi pregunta era sobre sql.

Decir que soy nuevo en esto.

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas deben ir en [meta].

Answer (score 1):

Cuando editas la pregunta vuelves a actualizar , es bueno editar la pregunta así evitas hacer spam en la plataforma. También te puedes ayudar añadiendo un comentario y avisando que ya actualízaste la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

La página principal así como la página de preguntas de forma predeterminada ordenan las preguntas por actividad por lo que si editas tu pregunta esta se moverá a la parte superior y permacerá ahí hasta que otra pregunta sea publicada o editada más recientemente.

Si tu edición se deriva de un comentario sería bueno que agregaras una @respuesta para notificar al autor del comentario de que que has editado tu pregunta (lo mismo para las respuestas).

Relacionado

- [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/65)