# ¿Cómo citar a un usuario en respuesta?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, convenciones-sociales

El caso es el siguiente: En la pregunta [Función distinta cuando hago click en un div](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310628/funci%c3%b3n-distinta-cuando-hago-click-en-un-div) un usuario dio una respuesta, a mi parecer acertada, pero un poco corta. Me pareció buena idea agregar un `fragmento de código` para que el OP pudiera ver el código propuesto en acción. Evidentemente, esto no lo podía haber hecho en un comentario, por lo que creé una respuesta adicional indicando que solo era la propuesta de la respuesta inicial "en acción".

Dado que la intención no era "robarme" (en el buen sentido) la respuesta que me gustó, intenté citar al usuario que había hecho la respuesta, sin embargo, pese a intentar utilizar el "@" no fue posible que esta "cita" se viera como quería.

Surgen varias preguntas aquí:

1. ¿Estuvo bien hacerlo de esta manera?, si no es así,:
2. ¿Cuál debería ser la forma adecuada según las normas de SOes?
3. En caso de que estuviera bien, (Y en otros posibles escenarios donde se requiera citar a un usuario de SO en una respuesta), ¿Cómo se hace?, ¿Se podrá pedir un #new-feature para esto?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si con notificación te refieres a que *algo* llegue a la bandeja de entrada, no hay manera: en [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/209901) <sub>en inglés</sub> puedes ver todo aquello que lanzan una notificación y mencionar a un usuario en el cuerpo de una pregunta no lo hace.

Si quieres que llegue una notificación en los comentarios, hazlo según lo indicado en [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83).

Para este caso concreto, no hay una manera canónica. La clave es mantener la educación y dejar claro que no estás apropiándote de nada sino colaborando a hacer la solución un poco mejor.
A mí me parece que siempre es útil comentar en la respuesta del usuario en cuestión, indicándoselo. Si les gusta tu opción y a ti te parece bien, siempre puedes sugerir que "meta" tu respuesta dentro de la suya y luego tú borras la tuya.

Para mencionar al usuario a mí me gusta enlazar la otra respuesta en cuestión. El nombre de usuario puede cambiar, por lo que decir *como dice @Edwin* puede pasar a no tener sentido si pasa a llamarse Pepito.