# Actividad del usuario: preguntas: ordenar por vistas

Tags: característica-nueva, actividad-reciente

Solo una sugerencia.

Arriba a la derecha, al lado de la foto, cuando clickeas ves la actividad del usuario, en este caso la propia. Vas a la sección preguntas y puedes ordenarlas de varias maneras, según votos, etc... Sería posible ordenarlas según el número de vistas?

Comment: Ya es así: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/154434/iria?tab=questions&sort=views Proporciona un enlace si te refieres a otra cosa

Comment: Ahora que estaba mirando esto..a alguien mas le pasa que si va a la pestaña Respuestas y dentro de ahi a Respuestas, parece que se ve bastante raro? [Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh?tab=responses&sort=answers&StartDate=2019-12-05%2009:39:27Z)

Comment: Eso me ha pasado en la respuesta a alguna pregunta que se ha borrado. Supongo que al borrarse la pregunta, no se elimina el enlace a la respuesta, así que donde queda referenciado sale el error 404

Comment: @Pikoh puedes usar `/users/current?` para que el enlace vaya al de cada cual (el mío al mío, el tuyo al tuyo, etc). Como moderador puedes ver esa pestaña de todo el mundo, pero el resto de humanos no podemos :D (ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=responses) Dicho lo cual, sí: se ve fatal, como roto de formato. Lo he visto reportado en Meta.SE hace no mucho.

Comment: ¿Podrías clarificar @Iria si lo que dije en mi primer comentario responde a tu duda? ¿O te refieres a alguna otra cosa?

Comment: No, el enlace me dirige a las respuestas, clickeo en preguntas y me salen las vistas de cada una, no tengo muchas (solo 4 ahora mismo), por lo que no es un problema el hecho de que no estén ordenadas por vistas, pero si tuviera bastantes más (pongamos 50), estas obviamente estarían desordenadas, pero ordenarlas sería más tedioso para el usuario, al tener que ir a través de todas las páginas

Comment: ¿Qué enlace, @Iria? Usa por cierto `@usuario` para que lleguen las notificaciones. Lee [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83) para más info.

Comment: cliqueo en es.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=responses y  me sale lo mío reestructurado (por eso de current, me parece a mí...)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' vaya,tienes razon!! Pensé que podía todo el mundo, dado que se puede acceder a varias pestañas del perfil de cualquier usuario, pero ya veo que no a la _responses_

Comment: Vale, si ya lo veo. Se puede ordenar por vistas, sin embargo, si sigues el procedimiento descrito anteriormente no

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no está claro qué se pregunta

Answer (score -1):

Después de jugar un rato, resulta que si sigues el procedimiento descrito, te muestra un resumen pero no te muestra las preguntas ordenadas por vistas, para ello tienes que clickear en vistas