# ¿Qué ocurre cuando menciono a alguien con @elUsuario en un comentario de edición?

Tags: soporte, ediciones, notificaciones

Cuando se edita una pregunta/respuesta se puede poner un comentario de edición.

¿Qué ocurre si menciono a alguien en ese comentario? ¿El usuario es notificado? ¿Qué tipo de notificación recibe?

¿O el usuario no es notificado? ¿Por qué no es notificado?

He aquí un ejemplo:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 7):

No ocurre nada: el usuario no es notificado. El texto de edición de una publicación es libre (puede ponerse lo que se quiera) pero aislado de cualquier tipo de experiencia de usuario, por lo que no dispara las notificaciones.

Las únicas menciones con `@` que tienen efecto son las que se hacen en los comentarios y están descritas en [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83).