# ¿Se está usando más la "@referencia" a la hora de mencionar a usuarios en la zona de comentarios de las respuestas?

Tags: discusión, comentarios, notificaciones, respuestas-a-comentarios

Hay [un](https://es.traducir.win/strings/1701) [par](https://es.traducir.win/strings/6475) de cadenas del tipo siguiente que aparecen como "placeholder" en el espacio de los comentarios de debajo de las respuestas:

> Original String:  Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information.  Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”.

En es.traducir.win propuse hace unos meses la traducción con una coletilla final y fueron aceptadas, de modo que ahora tenemos lo siguiente (pongo en negrita lo que añadí):

> Utiliza los comentarios para pedir una aclaración o para añadir más información. Evita los comentarios como “+1” o “gracias”. **Utiliza @nombre para responder a otras personas que hayan comentado, si quieres que sean notificadas.**

Es decir, recomendando usar lo que se describe en [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83).

Pregunta: ¿habéis notado si últimamente se usan más las `@referencias` que antes? Es decir, ¿ha tenido algún impacto? Yo particularmente no, pero tampoco he estado muy presente en conversaciones de comentarios. Si funcionara, podría añadirse también en el "placeholder" de debajo de las preguntas.

Comment: Yo personalmente no he notado diferencia. Pero es cierto que, al menos en mi caso, en muy pocas ocasiones me han referenciado sin @ la verdad.Ni antes ni ahora

Comment: ¿Si se usan más que cuándo? No encontré una forma de saber cuándo se modificó agregando el "@" en el placeholder

Comment: @Pikoh ¿y ahora? (-perdón, no pude evitarlo!)

Comment: @Pikoh ¿podrías revisar en algún momento [esta publicación de Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356261/209901) y ver si los moderadores recibís alguna notificación en caso de publicaciones que tienen tantos votos de cierre en la cola de baja calidad pero que no terminan de cerrar?

Comment: Pues no. O no al menos que yo sepa. Si que yo hace algun tiempo revisaba las publicaciones con votos de cierre para mirar las que tenían 3-4 y borrarlas si consideraba que lo merecían, pero hace tiempo que no me paso por ahi. En realidad, se supone que nos iban a reducir los votos necesarios para cerrar a 3 si no recuerdo mal...pero nunca mas se supo

Comment: @Pikoh mil gracias por mirarlo. El sistema cojea bastante en este sentido. Mira esta otra: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/217706 un montón de votos de cierre pero un solo "Se ve bien" la marca como buena. Leí por allí que lo de pasar de 5 a 3 votos se implementará este Q4, veremos... Parece más útil que el blingbling del modo oscuro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No particularmente

Hay un mayor porcentaje de arrobados que a principio de año, pero significativamente menos que el año pasado.

**Porcentaje de Comentarios con `@` sobre total de comentarios desde enero 2019**

[image: Curva de porcentaje]

Fuente: https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1318600/comentarios-con#graph

Comment: Supongo que una respuesta así te baja el espíritu... No mates al mensajero

Comment: solamente un 15% y en los mejores momentos :O Genial por la gráfica, se me ocurren ciertos elementos a tener en cuenta: los datos recientes incluyen las publicaciones que roomba no se ha cargado, mientras que en las antiguas esto ya ha desaparecido. Típicamente, esas publicaciones suelen tener menos calidad, luego más "fallos" y probablemente el tema de comentarios sin avisar. Luego, el tema de que las `@menciones` son útiles cuando hay más de una persona comentando.

Comment: Claro. La forma correcta de evaluarlo me parece que sería comparando contra la cantidad de veces que se usa el nombre de otro usuario sin arrobar, el cual no se estaría notificando. Además, descartando comentarios con `@` que no estén dirigidos a un usuario. Pero se me hace complicado el query. Me pareció que sacar el porcentaje total era una aproximación "aceptable".